# Drawing the smallest value from a set of distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, extreme-value

I have a specific number of normal distributions $N_D$ all with their own mean $\mu$ and std $\sigma$. Now I obtain a sample from all distributions which results in a set of $N_D$ samples. What is the probability that the smallest value from this set comes from the distribution with the smallest mean $\mu$?

This problem is illustrated by the picture below. Translating the problem statement to this picture means that we sample a value from the 4 distributions $E$ ,$F$ ,$B$ ,$D$. Now what is the probability that the smallest value from this set comes from the distribution with the smallest mean $\mu$? Which is $E$ for this case.

[image: Overlapping distributions]

I now have a setup which takes a large number of samples and calculates the probability in this way. However for simulation speed, I would like an analytical expression which gives this probability for any number of distributions with known means and sigmas I give as input.

I'm aware this questions has already been asked here for only two distributions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/probability-of-a-point-taken-from-a-certain-normal-distribution-will-be-greater
However, I was not able to extend this solution to my problem.

Comment: This can't be answered at present. What are the means? How far apart are they? How many distributions do you have? Do they all have the same SD? What?

Comment: That is the thing. I'm looking for a generic formula where I can plug in:
-number of distributions $N_D$
-mean $\mu$ and std $\sigma$ of each distribution

Comment: I would look into the Weibull distribution, which characterizes a distribution sampled max/minim